# Updating Table in DBT

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbt

I have two SQL scripts and am trying to translate them to DBT.

Problem Statment is as below:-

[image]

**Current Solution**

SQL script No.1 creates the table and SQL script No.2 update the table with the following query

```
UPDATE T1 
SET C4 = 3.3 WHERE C1 = 'US'
```

Now, I want to move these creation and updation job(Script1 and Script 2) to DBT.

**DBT Solution**

I have created a model called T1.sql in DBT which creates Table T1 in the database and its contents are as follows:-

```
SELECT * FROM member;
```

Now for updating the table as per the above-mentioned criteria, I wrote the SELECT statement as

```
Select c1,c2,c3,
case when c1 = ‘US’ then 3.3 else c4 end as c4
from t1
```

Now the question is where do I put this above the SELECT statement. I cannot put in file **T1.sql** as each DBT model file should have only one SELECT statement. If new file, then what should be the file name. I cannot have multiple files with the name 'T1.sql'.

Is there any way we can include both these operations in T1.sql file so that we need not to create any other new tables to achieve this?

Comment: @Gaganoreet check the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your `T1.sql` file:

```
SELECT * FROM member
```

This query returns the table `T1` as you mentioned.

Now you can create a new sql file in dbt for example `T2.sql` and this `T2.sql` will have the following code:

```
select 
t1.*,
case when t1.c1 = ‘US’ then 3.3 else c4 end as c4
from {{ref('T1')}} as t1
```

Here T2.sql file is `referencing` the model `T1` which is basically your `T1.sql` file .

**Code 2** with CTE
This will be your entire t1.sql file: Updates your c4 values based on case statement provided

```
With initial_data as (
select * from member
)
select 
initital_data.*,
case when initital_data.c1 = ‘US’ then 3.3 else c4 end as c4
from initial_data as t1
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that in one model only? because now I'll have a table with the name T2 with my updated results. But the original requirement was to update table T1

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh is that what you need ? I have updated the code

Comment: if you will run dbt run --models t1 , then this model will update the values as you want (case statement)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question to give more clarity about my issue

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh i think you can run my code2 that should work

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh did you test

Comment: Thanks !! Just a doubt - after this update, I need to create several more tables and then I need to add another column to Table T1(these are operations in the current pipeline). How can I achieve this thing DBT?
In the SQL pipeline, It's simple as we can another SQL script which adds a new column and do the update query. But in DBT do we need to adjust that in T1.sql only?

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh use CTE like in code 2,  create new tables then join it to table 1 and in the final select statement you will have updated values, if the solution is fine for you can you do the upvote and accept answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236707/discussion-between-trillion-and-gaganpreet-singh).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to run a different query depending on an external status.

You could add a flag as a DBT Variable[1](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables) and use different queries in case you are looking to update or create it again.

Assuming you call your variable "update" and value is a boolean, you can:

```
{% if update %}
Select c1,c2,c3,
case when c1 = ‘US’ then 3.3 else c4 end as c4
from t1
{% else %}
SELECT * FROM member;
{% endif %}
```

You can also set the variable at the beginning of the sql file using:

```
{% set update = True %}
```

Comment: How can I change the value of the 'update' variable in run time? or may be like, for the first time I want the value to be **false** and then it should change to **true**

Comment: @GaganpreetSingh you can pass it as an argument like this: dbt run --vars '{"updated": True}'